# Paste Special - values only

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an audit trail DB, and have the managed to formulate some code to take each line to sheet 2, however I have fallen at the last and cannot work out how to paste values only?

here is my code thus far; any help greatly appreciated

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nxtRow As Integer, b As Boolean
    'Determine if change was to Column I (9)
   If Target.Column = 9 Then
        'If Yes, Determine if cell >= 1
       If IsError(Target.Value) Then
        b = True
    Else
        If Target.Value >= 1 Then
            b = True
        Else
            b = False
        End If
        End If
        If b Then
        'If Yes, find next empty row in Sheet 2
       nxtRow = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'Copy changed row and paste into Sheet 2
       Target.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A" & nxtRow)
            End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks
Matt

Comment: I notice some fatal errors in your code, but I don't think that if I correct them that fixes your problem. Want me to put it as an answer anyways?

Comment: yes please, the more stable the better, have pulled this together from a bit of google work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not solve the problem but it will improve your code.
you open some If-statements but you don't close some which will make your code do something else than you want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nxtRow As Integer, b As Boolean
    'Determine if change was to Column I (9)
   If Target.Column = 9 Then
        'If Yes, Determine if cell >= 1
       If IsError(Target.Value) Then ' You open this If but you don't close it
        b = True
       'if you don't close it here the next line (else) will be the else of this if
       End If 
   Else
        If Target.Value >= 1 Then
            b = True
        Else
            b = False
        End If
      'this line had an else if as well. which would just stop your main if statement
        If b = True Then 
        'you say 'if b then' on the line above, which basically does nothing
        'If you want to check if b = True for example, do what I did above

        'If Yes, find next empty row in Sheet 2
             nxtRow = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            'Copy changed row and paste into Sheet 2
            Target.EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A" & nxtRow)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To paste values, you can copy to the clipboard then use the `PasteSpecial` method, for example:

```
 Target.EntireRow.Copy
 Sheets(2).Range("A" & nxtRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: I get a compile error on this - invalid outside procedure.  Do I paste this to This Workbook, or add to my code?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your code carefully enough! You can use this but you'll have to copy via the clipboard - see edited answer.